# How can I resize partition to utilize the extra space in Gparted

Tags: gparted

I have booted with "Parted Magic ISO" to see my hard drive.  I have 430 Gig's free.

[image: My Hard Drive]

Answer (score 0):

1. Move swap partition `sda2` to the end of your disk.
2. Resize `sda1` to maximum.

Don't be afraid to experiment **to the point** where you press "Apply All Operations" - this is where actual disk writes will start.

Comment: Or move swap to end of drive and create a data partition or /home. Often system is more efficient (slightly) if all system files are closer together on large drives, so a 20 or 25GB / (root) is better.

Comment: @oldfred, yes, but the difference is marginal and usually not worth the headache of eventually running out of space on your root partition.

Comment: Just for reference, I use about 11GB of my / partition including /home which is about 2GB only because of .wine with Picasa. But I do try to move as much data to my data partition. If a user has a separate /home then / is not normally large nor should be.